# Battery usage by certain applications

Tags: battery

Can I find out how much battery takes running of certain application?
The goal is to minimize using applications that take a lot of battery and maximize battery persistence before having to recharge.

Comment: That question makes no sense as all apps and services will one way or another, suck up battery juice, and don't forget including wifi, bluetooth and 3G data. Mileage will vary from one user to the next. Screen display time, running services, what apps are active.. not to mention, is the cpu overclocked, what governor is running in the kernel, etc ... far too many variables in the equation that you just simply cannot pin down..

Comment: Whatever you do, don't even think of going down the road of killing the apps that you perceive to be sucking up the most battery juice either! ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you go to Settings -> Battery(settings -> about phone -> battery in < ICS) . You'll see battery usage by everything running on your phone. If some certain application consumes very high battery, it will be listed there along with battery usage. You can then minimize use of such application.

[image]

Comment: That's strange but in `settings -> about phone -> battery use` there aren't any applications in my phone, but there are running applications.

Comment: I don't remember seeing any application until and unless it eats at least 2 % of the battery.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a newer version of android (Ice Cream Sandwich) you just go to Settings > Battery, and you'll find a list of what's sucking the most battery.

Answer (score 1):

I see.. Your main concern is to save battery life and identify which app consumes the most of your battery.

You can use the hidden built-in android battery usage monitor using the guide below.

Dial this code in your phone dialer *** # * # 4636 # * # *** then press on **Usage statistics**

[image: Usage Statistics]
[image: Usage Time]

From here you could see how long your app is running even if it's running as service ex.(update gps position, get movement xyz axis for pedometer, compass, wifi/network location, barometer, Ambient Light Sensor or etc).